# Don't understand: Which questions/answers can I edit?

Tags: support

It's a strange behavior, at least to me. Sometimes I see the "edit" link below a question/answer of others, usually I don't see it. So what kind of question/answer can I edit? Or it's a bug?

And sometimes I see that others can edit my question, too.

Here is a question/answers I have the right to edit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784461/how-do-you-clear-your-mind-after-a-day-of-coding-closed

For example, I can't see the link to edit in this question: [PHP search key in array and return its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467071/php-search-key-in-array-and-return-its-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

The former is a community wiki post, so it only needs 100 rep to edit.

The latter is not, so you'd need 2000 rep to be allowed to edit it.

If you go to your [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges), you can see how close you are to any given privilege.

Comment: But I think the wiki tag is no longer valid?

Comment: @Hoàng - some of Community Wiki's aspects have changed, but that's not one of them.